# how to solve "findall() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'" error for reading a file in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to extract specific lines from two .txt files using keywords and write the entire found lines in another output.txt file. here is an exmple of my desired file:

My input files are like below:

**Input1.txt**

Pore limiting diameter in A: 3.95
Maximum pore diameter in A: 8.02
The system is percolated in 1 dimension (channels)

**Input2.txt**

Pore limiting diameter in A: 4.15
Maximum pore diameter in A: 7.02
The system is percolated in 1 dimension (channels)

My output.txt file must be  like below:

Pore limiting diameter in A: 3.95   #####   Maximum pore diameter in A: 8.02(* from input1.txt)

Pore limiting diameter in A: 4.15   #####   Maximum pore diameter in A: 7.02(* from input2.txt)

I wrote a code like the below:

```
import re
filenames = [f"result{i}.txt" for i in range(1,3)]

with open ("output.txt", "w") as outputfiles:

for file in filenames:
    with open (file) as inputfile:
        content = inputfile.read()
        desired = re.findall('Pore limiting diameter in A.*|Maximum pore diameter in A.*')
for line in desired:
    outputfiles.writelines(line + ' ###### ')
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: from official documentation(https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) , you can see you need to call `re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)`  you are only providing string. You need to provide search pattern first, then string.

Comment: And it is not possible to help you with what you are trying to achieve without some sample and you telling us what exactly do you want to find in the txt file.

Comment: Dear @BijayRegmi,Thanks for your comment. I have edited my question with an example of my desired output.txt file. I added even "content" in re.findall('string' , content). The error disappeared but it gave me information from my first input file( input1.txt) only.

Comment: Does each input file contain only 1 line of text or could it contain multiple lines?

Comment: @itproh66 There are multiple lines in each input file and I want just two lines as I wrote keywords of my desired lines in my code.

Comment: dear @itproh66 I could solve the problem by adding ("string" , content) in my code.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mohammad,
There are a couple of problem with your code as written.
1, the format for re.findall is as follows `re.findall('search Pattern', text to search)` your command is missing the text to search.  Thus change the line to `desired = re.findall('Pore limiting diameter in A.*|Maximum pore diameter in A.*', contents)`
2. The search pattern is incorrect based on your sample text files it should be changed to ```'Pore limiting diameter in A:*|Maximum pore diameter in A:*'``  `
3. The for loop for outputting data needs to be indented under the  the file read element of your code.
4. You have failed to include the source of the data in your output data.

Here is how your code should look after making these changes:

```
import re
filenames = [f"result{i}.txt" for i in range(1,3)]

with open ("output.txt", "w") as outputfiles:

    for file in filenames:
        with open (file) as inputfile:
            content = inputfile.read()
            desired = re.findall('Pore limiting diameter in A:*|Maximum pore diameter in A:*', contents)
            for line in desired:
                outputfiles.writelines(f"{line[0]} ###### {line[1]}(* from {file})")
```